# How do I manually reset the Moonstruck simulation?

Tags: prey

Due to bad luck/RNG on my part, one of my characters died fairly early in a Moonstruck DLC run, which forces you to play as a different character and has essentially halted my forward progress in unlocking remaining characters.

Is there any way to reset the simulation so I can play as this character without having to play as all the other characters first?

Note: "New Game" erases all your shared progress, so this isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the in-game dialog, when you complete 25% of the simulation, you get the Reset Simulation option on the character select screen (hold down <kbd>Del</kbd> in the PC version).

However, this may have changed during development as both myself and a friend didn't unlock Reset Simulation in our games until we finished our current run after unlocking the third playable character.  In my case, I died.  In my friend's case, he escaped.